# Clone only attributes that are not functions

Tags: javascript, lodash

Basically I have some objects that I need only their data without any function inside them, e.g:

```
var obj1 = {
  test: function() {
    doSomeStuff();
  },
  foo: 'bar',
}

var obj2 = _.someThing(obj1);

> obj2 = {
  foo: 'bar'
}
```

I have started with something like this, but it's not exactly what I want,

```
_.mapValues(obj1, function(value) {
  if (_.isFunction(value)) {
    return false;
  }
  return value
});

> { test: false, foo: 'bar' }
```

Highly preferred solutions with `lodash`.

Comment: *"but it's not exactly what I want"* What is it doing you don't want? What does it not do that you *do* want? Where are you stuck? You seem to have all the pieces.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i don't need `test` attribute to be set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [_.pick](https://lodash.com/docs#pick) function, like this

```
var res = _.pick(obj1, function (el) {
  return !_.isFunction(el);
})
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/ruleqe/1/edit?js,output)